# Prove that $(\Bbb C, \cdot )$ is not a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

For $(\Bbb C,\cdot)$ to be a group, it has to satisfy three axioms:

1. operation $\cdot$ is associative
2. there exists an element $e\in \Bbb C$ such that for all $c\in \Bbb C$ we have $e\cdot c=c\cdot e= c$
3. each element $c\in \Bbb C$ has an inverse $b$ such that $c\cdot b=b\cdot c=e$

My claim is that $(\Bbb C, \cdot)$ is a group because it satisfies all axioms:
It is associative, it has identity element $1$ and there is a multiplicative inverse for every element.

But my textbook says prove it is not a group and I don't see why it is not a group.

Comment: each element has inverse? What about $0$?

Comment: oh right... There is no b for c=0 such that b*0=0*b=1. So, it is not a group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Lemma:** Each group has exactly one [idempotent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence); namely, its identity.

*Proof:* Suppose $x$ is an idempotent in a group $G$ with identity $e\neq x$. Then, by definition, $xx=x^2=x=xe$. Multiply on the left by $x^{-1}$. Then $x=e$, a contradiction. $\square$

But in $(\Bbb C, \cdot)$, we have $0\cdot 0=0$ and $1\cdot 1=1$.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension of Shaun's answer and Phicar's comment, note that both of them brought up $0$ as being the point of pain. If we consider $(\mathbb{C} - \{0\}, \cdot)$, then this *is* a group.